# Laravel 5.6 DB::RAW count()

Tags: laravel

How do I count the number of rows in `score` column where score is less than 50?

```
 $user = DB::table('users')
 ->leftJoin('rankings', 'rankings.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
 ->select('users.*', DB::raw("(  (count(rankings.score)  ) )  as `countBelow50` ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the advanced join clauses: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins

```
$user = DB::table('users')
      ->leftJoin('rankings', function($join) {
                $join->on('rankings.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                           ->where('rankings.score','<','50');
             })
      ->select('users.*', DB::raw("(  (count(rankings.score)  ) )  as `countBelow50` ")
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the query inside the DB::raw, as `countBelow50`? Becuase I need the whole data in the leftJoin part.